# How to define a ref struct in F# in .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: f#, ref-struct

When [F# 4.5 was announced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/08/14/announcing-f-4-5/), it was stated that:

> The F# feature set is comprised of
>
> - [...]
> - The ability to produce IsByRefLike structs (examples of such structs: Span<'T>and ReadOnlySpan<'T>).

How to "produce" these types? I tried the `[<IsByRefLike>]` attribute but is was not found in .NET Standard 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with .NET SDK 6.0.200 (available in Visual Studio 2022 17.1), the F# compiler recognizes user-defined `IsByRefLikeAttribute`s. The following code will transparently enable defining ref structs on .NET Standard 2.0 as well as later frameworks:

```ml
#if NETSTANDARD2_0
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices

open System

[<Sealed; AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Struct)>]
type IsByrefLikeAttribute() = inherit Attribute()
#endif

namespace MyLibrary

open System
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<IsByRefLike>]
type MyRefStruct(span: Span<int>) = struct end
```

Answer (score 3):

The attribute is found in `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Struct; IsByRefLike>]
type Apa =
    { A: Span<int>
      B: int }
```

Phillip Carter talks about this in [What's new in F# 4.5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxVqnmcj8eA) (about 21 min. in).

It is available for .NET Core and .NET Framework, but not .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have tried it, but unfortunately, this attribute does not exist in .NET Core. I will change the wording of my question.

Comment: Indeed, it's not available in .NET Standard 2.0, only in .NET Core and .NET Framework. It is announced to be included in .NET Standard 2.1, though.

Answer (score -3):

Technically, this is not an answer.

**First**, according to the specs, `IsByRefLike` is for the compiler, not for the developers to use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.isbyreflikeattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

**Second**, when we do want something from a compiler, then it is crucial that we do understand what we want from it. So a correct question could be: *I need ABC because I need to do XYZ*, where `ABC` would be something related to `IsByRefLike` and then `XYZ` would be something based on `IsByRefLike`. The question does not explain why `IsByRefLike` is needed.

I think that a minimalist approach should be always weighted in when considering which language features to use / not to use: do we really need some particular language feature to accomplish what we need? F# `Option.bind` comes to mind: if the function is a one-liner then `Option.bind` is great. However, if there is some tree of how to parse the result, then it might be better to do that explicitly without using `Option.bind`.

So the questions are:

1. Do you really need `IsByRefLike`?
2. If you think that you do, could you, please, post an example of where you actually **do** need it.

Comment: 1. No, my code can do without it. The data structure in question is not holding another ref struct.

2. I had thought about using it to enforce that the type stays on the stack, for safety and correctness reasons.

Comment: @TheodoreTsirpanis I think that where the data is located should the least of developer's concern unless it is explicitly needed due to some reason. I've given F# tasks to sort list of millions elements and it did just fine. So, I suggest that you forget about this attribute unless / until you really need it.